# Syntax Error Symfony2 Query

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine-query

Hi I have following join query.

```
return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
            "SELECT t1.taskId,t1.title,t1.dueDate,t1.modified,cb.forename,cb.surname,up.profilePhotoPath,
            (SELECT tp.metaData,tp.content FROM AppBundle:J1TaskPost tp order by tp.created DESC ) AS taskPost
            FROM AppBundle:J1Task as t1
            JOIN t1.assignees As ta
            JOIN t1.createdBy As cb
            JOIN AppBundle:J1UserProfile as up WITH t1.createdBy = up.user
            WHERE t1.deleted IS NULL and t1.status = false and ta.userid=$userId group by t1.taskId order by tp.created desc"
        )->getResult();
```

It is throwing the following error:

```
Syntax Error] line 0, col 130: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_FROM, got ','.
```

I am not able to find out what is missing in above query.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line:

```
"SELECT t1.taskId,t1.title,t1.dueDate,t1.modified,cb.forename,cb.surname,up.profilePhotoPath,
(SELECT tp.metaData,tp.content FROM AppBundle:J1TaskPost tp order by tp.created DESC ) AS taskPost
```

You need to select the items within taskPost, but what you're doing here is to define the table instead. What you could do is:

```
SELECT t1.taskId,t1.title,t1.dueDate,t1.modified,cb.forename,cb.surname,up.profilePhotoPath, taskPost.metaData, taskPost.content FROM
(SELECT tp.metaData,tp.content FROM AppBundle:J1TaskPost tp order by tp.created DESC ) AS taskPost,
...
```

Comment: Hi Aculay I have tried this but getting another Error:
 return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery(
                "SELECT t1.taskId,t1.title,t1.dueDate,t1.modified,cb.forename,cb.surname,up.profilePhotoPath, taskPost.metaData, taskPost.content FROM
(SELECT tp.metaData,tp.content FROM AppBundle:J1TaskPost tp order by tp.created DESC ) AS taskPost

[Semantical Error] line 0, col 134 near '(SELECT tp.metaData,tp.content': Error: Class '(' is not defined.